# How can I write the functions in Cucumber?

Tags: function, testing, cucumber, watir-webdriver

How can I write the function in cucumber with watir-webdriver? I mean, I have same code and I don't want always to re-write it. I just want to write this function and then use it. This will help me to make my code shorter.

For example, this function:

```
def login
  @b.text_field(:id => `login`).set `login`
  @b.text_field(:id => `passw`).set `passw`
  @b.button(:id => `submit`).click
end
```

...and then I want to use it this way:

```
get :login
```

...but I don't know how to write it correctly.

Comment: Please provide example Cucumber and Watir code.

Comment: You should really read a book on Ruby. This has nothing to do with watir or cucumber. There are plenty of free ruby books on the internet.

Comment: Kurt, you gotta ask yourself why you don't get a lot of answers. You might start with taking comments seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def login
  @b.text_field(:id => `login`).set `login`
  @b.text_field(:id => `passw`).set `passw`
  @b.button(:id => `submit`).click
end

login
```